# intent null error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-spinner

After sorting out my code I keep getting a null on my second screen when i hit the submit button having trouble spotting my mistake any help would be appreciated.

first class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class IwiSelect extends Activity {

Spinner spinner1, spinner2, spinner3, spinner4, spinner5;
Button btnSubmit; 
String iwi1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iwiselect);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_iwi_select, menu);
    return true;
}




// get the selected drop down list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5);

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            String text = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("spinnerText", text);
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(IwiSelect.this, SecondScreenActivity.class);

            //Sending data to another Activity
            nextScreen.putExtra("USERNAME", iwi1);
            //nextScreen.putExtra(spinner2.getContext().toString(), false);





            // starting new activity
            startActivity(nextScreen);




}
    });

  }
  }
```

this first class the user selects from a spinner (will have 5 spinners in total)

second class

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {

TextView FirstIwi;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selected_iwi);





    FirstIwi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     Intent intent = getIntent();


    String text = intent.getStringExtra("spinnerText");
    //Spinner spinnername2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);



    FirstIwi.setText("First Iwi  " + text);


}
```

}

this activity is for selecting an option from a spinner

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IwiSelect" >

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/IwiList"
    android:prompt="@string/Iwi_prompt" />

 <Spinner
 android:id="@+id/spinner4"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner5"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
 android:entries="@array/IwiList"
 android:prompt="@string/Iwi_prompt" />

 <Spinner
 android:id="@+id/spinner3"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/spinner5"
 android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
 android:entries="@array/IwiList"
 android:prompt="@string/Iwi_prompt" />

 <Spinner
 android:id="@+id/spinner5"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
 android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
 android:entries="@array/IwiList"
 android:prompt="@string/Iwi_prompt" />

 <Spinner
 android:id="@+id/spinner2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
 android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
 android:entries="@array/IwiList"
 android:prompt="@string/Iwi_prompt" />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:onClick="onClick"
 android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this activity is for displaying the selected options

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IwiSelect" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="TEXT"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
nextScreen.putExtra("USERNAME", iwi1);
```

Then start the second Activity using the `nextScreen` Intent. You never use the `intent` Intent, which has the `"spinnerText"` key.

Then, when you get the extra in the second Activity, you are doing

```
String text = intent.getStringExtra("spinnerText");
```

Which references a non-existent key for the intent (`nextScreen`), and so, text will be `null`. On screen you most likely see `First Iwi null`.

Consider changing it to:

```
String text = intent.getStringExtra("USERNAME");
```

instead.